# Keras InvalidArgumentError: graph execution error closed

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, keras

Пытаюсь написать модель, предсказывающую классификацию МСС кодов. В Keras я новичок. Помогите исправить ошибку

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import LSTM, Dense, Embedding
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

f_train = pd.read_csv('/kaggle/input/alfabankchallengedata/df_train.csv', sep=';')
df_test = pd.read_csv('/kaggle/input/alfabankchallengedata/df_test.csv', sep=';')

df_train['Data'] = df_train['Data'].apply(lambda x: [int(item) for item in x.split(',')] if isinstance(x, str) else x)
df_train['Target'] = df_train['Target'].apply(lambda x: [int(item) for item in x.split(',')] if isinstance(x, str) else x)
df_train

X_train=df_train['Data']
y_train=df_train['Target']

encoder=LabelEncoder()
X_train_encoder=[encoder.fit_transform(seq) for seq in X_train]
y_train_encoder=[encoder.fit_transform(seq) for seq in y_train]

max_sequence_length = 10  
X_train_padded = pad_sequences(X_train_encoder, maxlen=max_sequence_length, padding='post', truncating='post')
Y_train_padded = pad_sequences(y_train_encoder, maxlen=max_sequence_length, padding='post', truncating='post')

model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(input_dim=len(encoder.classes_), output_dim=50, input_length=10))
model.add(LSTM(128))
model.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

Epoch 1/10
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[62], line 1
----> 1 model.fit(X_train_padded, Y_train_padded, epochs=10, batch_size=64, validation_split=0.2)

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py:70, in filter_traceback.<locals>.error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
     67     filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
     68     # To get the full stack trace, call:
     69     # `tf.debugging.disable_traceback_filtering()`
---> 70     raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
     71 finally:
     72     del filtered_tb

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/execute.py:52, in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
     50 try:
     51   ctx.ensure_initialized()
---> 52   tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
     53                                       inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
     54 except core._NotOkStatusException as e:
     55   if name is not None:

InvalidArgumentError: Graph execution error:

Detected at node 'sequential_7/embedding_6/embedding_lookup' defined at (most recent call last):
    File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
      return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
    File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
      exec(code, run_globals)
    File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py", line 17, in <module>
      app.launch_new_instance()
    File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 1043, in launch_instance
      app.start()
    File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelapp.py", line 728, in start
      self.io_loop.start()
    File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tornado/platform/asyncio.py", line 195, in start
      self.asyncio_loop.run_forever()
    File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line 603, in run_forever
      self._run_once()
    File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1909, in _run_once
      handle._run()
    File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/asyncio/events.py", line 80, in _run
      self._context.run(self._callback, *self._args)
    File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 513, in dispatch_queue
      await self.process_one()
    File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 502, in process_one
      await dispatch(*args)
    File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 409, in dispatch_shell
      await result
    File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 729, in execute_request
      reply_content = await reply_content
    File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ipykernel/ipkernel.py", line 422, in do_execute
      res = shell.run_cell(
    File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ipykernel/zmqshell.py", line 540, in run_cell
      return super().run_cell(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3009, in run_cell
      result = self._run_cell(
    File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3064, in _run_cell
      result = runner(coro)
    File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/IPython/core/async_helpers.py", line 129, in _pseudo_sync_runner
      coro.send(None)
    File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3269, in run_cell_async
      has_raised = await self.run_ast_nodes(code_ast.body, cell_name,
    File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3448, in run_ast_nodes
      if await self.run_code(code, result, async_=asy):
    File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3508, in run_code
      exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
    File "/tmp/ipykernel_32/2855402681.py", line 1, in <module>
      model.fit(X_train_padded, Y_train_padded, epochs=10, batch_size=64, validation_split=0.2)
    File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 65, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1685, in fit
      tmp_logs = self.train_function(iterator)
    File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1284, in train_function
      return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1268, in step_function
      outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1249, in run_step
      outputs = model.train_step(data)
    File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1050, in train_step
      y_pred = self(x, training=True)
    File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 65, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 558, in __call__
      return super().__call__(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 65, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 1145, in __call__
      outputs = call_fn(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 96, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/engine/sequential.py", line 412, in call
      return super().call(inputs, training=training, mask=mask)
    File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/engine/functional.py", line 512, in call
      return self._run_internal_graph(inputs, training=training, mask=mask)
    File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/engine/functional.py", line 669, in _run_internal_graph
      outputs = node.layer(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 65, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 1145, in __call__
      outputs = call_fn(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 96, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/layers/core/embedding.py", line 272, in call
      out = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(self.embeddings, inputs)
Node: 'sequential_7/embedding_6/embedding_lookup'
indices[0,1] = 10 is not in [0, 6)
     [[{{node sequential_7/embedding_6/embedding_lookup}}]] [Op:__inference_train_function_18693]
```

Comment: Уберите лучше квадратные скобки из заголовка а то возникает ассоциация с закрытым вопросом)

Comment: Добавьте **полный трейс ошибки** прямо в вопрос.